# Реализация чтения файла из Pastebin в Python

Tags: python

Хочу добавить в программу импорт текста с Pastebin.
На ввод что бы была часть ссылки после /.
А на выход в переменную записывалось содержимое файла Pastebin.

Comment: Хорошая идея! А проблема то в чём? Что-то конкретное не получается?

Comment: Как это сделать, даже идей никаких для реализации нет

Comment: Так не бывает. Начните с самого простого. Например, создайте переменную, которая будет хранить введённые данные. Затем с помощью конкатенации сформируйте ссылку и т. д. Как сделаете всё, что можете, поищите информацию о модуле `requests`. И только тогда, если в коде возникнет какая-то ошибка и Вы не сможете её решить, приложите свой код и задайте конкретный вопрос. При таком подходе Вам обязательно кто-то поможет, я в том числе.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from requests import get
>>> get("https://pastebin.com/raw/NdPPhy8q").text
'paste for stackoverflow'
```

https://habr.com/ru/post/126262/